# Error installing new CRM 2011/2013 Server or new organization

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Already tried everything with lot of google search but nothing, could not solve the problem.

I'm creating a Virtual Machine for testing to run CRM 2011/2013 and is connect to a active directory from which the user is maximum administrator of this AD.
Already installed all hot fix and changed the windows registry, but still no success, using the following steps on this website:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2584871/en-us

Also already tried changing the registry of

AutoGroupManagementOff = 1
and
VerifyDomainName = 1

The name of the domain and this:
Domain: maindomain.local
Computername: TEST-CRM.maindomain.local
Username: maindomain\admin

The user in question and AD administrator.

This is the error:

> 14:23:50|   Info| CrmAction execution time; ProvisionBusinessAction; 00:00:07.0686308
>   14:23:50|  Error| Installer Complete: OrganizationCreator - Error encountered
>   14:23:50|  Error| Exception occured during Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.OrganizationCreator: Action Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ProvisionBusinessAction failed.
>   InnerException:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SystemUserServiceInternal`1.RetrieveSpecialUsers(ExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SystemUserServiceInternal`1.RetrieveCountCurrentUsersFilteredBy(ExecutionContext context, Int32 accessMode, Boolean useUpdateLock)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SystemUserServiceInternal`1.ValidateUsersCount(ExecutionContext context, Int32 accessMode, Int32 additionalUsers)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.OrganizationSettingsCacheLoader.LoadCacheData(Guid key, ExecutionContext context)
>
> 14:23:50|   Info| Setting organization state.  New state = Failed
>   14:23:51|  Error| Create new Organization (Name=6a5f9fd8-f721-e311-becc-005056bd0078, Id=crmtest1) failed with Exception:
>   System.Exception: Action Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.ProvisionBusinessAction failed. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SystemUserServiceInternal`1.RetrieveSpecialUsers(ExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SystemUserServiceInternal`1.RetrieveCountCurrentUsersFilteredBy(ExecutionContext context, Int32 accessMode, Boolean useUpdateLock)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.SystemUserServiceInternal`1.ValidateUsersCount(ExecutionContext context, Int32 accessMode, Int32 additionalUsers)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.OrganizationSettingsCacheLoader.LoadCacheData(Guid key, ExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Caching.ObjectModelCacheLoader`2.LoadCacheData(TKey key, IOrganizationContext context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft say it ways is a known issue in our current build.. to try other Access Key or other CRM Build version. After change the Access Key it works, thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you have two options for installation in terms of the installing user's privileges:
First:

- Using Domain Admin Right.
- Delegate full control right on the dedicated OU.

If this is a test environment grant the user Domain Admin right and get it over with.

you can view more information about installation including video tutorials in http://dynamics.co.il